# Android Application Building Alternatives

Tags: android

I'm beginning to look into Android programming.

When developing a mobile application, are there other options besides using the SDK to develop a native application?

For instance, is it possible to develop an application using only web technologies?

If so, what is your experience on the different techniques (limitations, etc)?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you just want to build a website yes?  Then why not build a website?  I suppose you could just take an activity that does nothing except call another activity that opens up your webpage, and call it an app.

Comment: I'm just exploring my options.  I'm not necessarily interested in building a website.

Comment: I very much suggest you don't do this. Use the SDK. Websites server a purpose, and their purpose is NOT to make mobile or desktop applications.

Comment: Yes @Falmarri is correct.  If I was at all unclear, doing that is not a good solution, and you shouldn't do it. (Thus it was in the comments, not as an actual answer).

Answer (score 2):

With Gingerbread now you have the possibility to create an app just with the NDK using NativeActivity.

> This release of the NDK includes many
>   new APIs, most of which are introduced
>   to support the development of games
>   and similar applications that make
>   extensive use of native code. Using
>   the APIs, developers have direct
>   native access to events, audio,
>   graphics and window management,
>   assets, and storage. Developers can
>   also implement the Android application
>   lifecycle in native code with help
>   from the new NativeActivity class. For
>   detailed information describing the
>   changes in this release, read the
>   CHANGES.HTML document included in the
>   downloaded NDK package.

If you are willing to use web technologies I would recommend you this book:
[Programming the Mobile](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596807795).

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, is it possible to develop an application using only web technologies?

Yes. You can use PhoneGap, Rhodes, or Titanium Mobile for this.

> If so, what is your experience on the different techniques (limitations, etc)?

Of the three, I prefer PhoneGap, as it seems the cleanest and simplest. Rhodes might be good if you are a Rails developer and want to use that style of Web development on-device.

Answer (score 1):

You can also develop applications on top of Adobe AIR.

So it seems you have quite a few options:

- Java based app
- Native app
- Adobe AIR
- Mobile website